# How can I install Cython as a dependency for this program?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I'm following the instructions to install the project [Reactor-3](https://github.com/flags/Reactor-3) here: https://github.com/flags/Reactor-3/wiki

So far, I've:

1. Pulled the code down
2. Taken libtcod-mingw.dll from the [latest version of libtcod](http://doryen.eptalys.net/libtcod/download/) and put it in the root of the project

It says I need to have Cython installed as well. Downloading the Cython latest release, I'm not sure how to incorporate the contents of the zip with this project so I can compile the modules as per the instructions. Any pointers?

Comment: [`Cython`](http://cython.org/) installer for windows can be found on following page: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cython

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All they want you to do is have Cython installed before  setting up Reactor-3.

This means going to the Cython website and downloading their source files. Then unpackaging their source files and running

```
python setup.py install
```

or

```
easy_install cython
```

inside the extracted directory.

Note:

Reactor-3 instructions state running

```
python compile_cython_modules.py build_ext --inplace
```

after installing `Cython` as `compile_cython_modules.py` requires `Cython.disutils` to build the source.

Reference:

http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/install.html

https://github.com/flags/Reactor-3/blob/master/compile_cython_modules.py